# How to increase cross-sell products display limit in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

When i am adding upsell product it is showing more then 4 on product page.
But when i am assigning more then 4 product to cross-sell it's only showing 4 product on cart page.

I want to show more then 4 product in cross-sell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override **Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php** file.

> Create **Vendor/MyModule/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" type="Vendor\MyModule\Block\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" />
</config>
```

> Create **Vendor/MyModule/Block/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php**

```
namespace Vendor\MyModule\Block\Checkout\Block\Cart;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock as StockHelper;

class Crosssell extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory $productLinkFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\RelatedProducts $itemRelationsList,
        StockHelper $stockHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutSession,
            $productVisibility,
            $productLinkFactory,
            $itemRelationsList,
            $stockHelper,
            $data
        );

        $this->_maxItemCount = 8; //put ur limit here
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try your solutions and check.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also use the layout if you don't want to create a plugin.**

Create the file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell">
            <action method="setItemLimit">
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">5</argument> //Set Limit As Per Your Requirement
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

Comment: wouldn't this be for upsell, and not crosssell?